# Different behavior of chrome on desktop and android mobile while sending data to BLE device

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth, android-chrome

While connecting to BLE server on my ESP32 device, using ‘Web Bluetooth API’, I am experiencing a ‎strange behavior. ‎
I can connect and send/receive data using chrome browser on my desktop, but with chrome browser ‎on my android phone I cannot send data to BLE server on my device. ‎
I could not figure out what is the reason. Is Encoding/Decoding different on desktop and mobile ‎browser, some permission problem or json string is sent in some different ways, or **is there some limit of data length sent from mobile browser as I am able to send simple "hello world" string from mobile browser but I cannot send "hello world hello world hello world hello world" ?‎**
My code is as below:‎

```js
    btnconnect.addEventListener('click', submitted);‎
    var wifissid;‎
    var wifipw;‎
    var myjson;‎
    var decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');‎
    var encoder = new TextEncoder('utf-8');‎
    var characteristic1;‎
    async function submitted() {‎
    ‎  wifissid = document.getElementById("ssid").value;‎
    ‎  wifipw = document.getElementById("pw").value;‎
    ‎  xdid = document.getElementById("xdid").value;‎
    ‎  var obj = {‎
    ‎    ssid: wifissid,‎
    ‎    pw: wifipw,‎
    ‎    did: xdid,‎
    ‎  };‎
    
    ‎  myjson = JSON.stringify(obj);‎
    
    ‎  try {‎
    ‎    const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({‎
    ‎      filters: [{‎
    ‎        name: 'DEVICENAME'‎
    ‎      }],‎
    ‎      optionalServices: [‎‘xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx’‎]‎
                
    ‎    });‎
    ‎    const server = await device.gatt.connect();‎
    ‎    const service = await server.getPrimaryService(‎‘xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx’‎); ‎
    ‎    characteristic1 = await service.getCharacteristic(‘yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy’);‎
    ‎    await characteristic1.startNotifications();‎
    ‎    characteristic1.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged',‎
    ‎      handleNotifications);‎
    ‎    let valuesent = encoder.encode(myjson);‎
    ‎    await characteristic1.writeValue(valuesent);‎
    ‎    ‎
    ‎  } catch (error) {‎
    ‎    console.log( error);‎
    ‎  }‎
    
    ‎}‎
    async function handleNotifications(event) {‎
    ‎  let value = await event.target.value;‎
    ‎  let valDecoded = decoder.decode(value);‎
    ‎  if (valDecoded.includes("success")) {‎
    ‎  // Do something
    ‎  }‎
    ‎  if (valDecoded.includes("failed")) {‎
       // Do something
    ‎  }}‎
```

Comment: Can you provide logs as described at https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/file-web-bluetooth-bugs for Android to help diagnose this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response. Yes the size matters. For mobile devices Maximum Transmission Unit (MTU) has limit of 23 bytes, but practically you can send only 20 bytes. There are ways to tackle this. I solved my problem by writing to the characteristic multiple times.

Comment: can you post snippet of your code? Also can you please post sample of data you are writing ? I am facing similar issue and I tried writing multiple times but I am getting GATT Error Unknown.

Comment: I have the same issue.  Using chrome://bluetooth-internals/ on Android, I can only extract 20 bytes. When I try from windows or Linux I get the full output (~200 bytes).  But the interesting part is when I go back to Android after windows/Linux, Android gets the full output. In conclusion, Android is not limited to 20 bytes, it just seems to accept the MTU from the device (default 20) and does not negotiate a higher rate. - I am just putting this out there as the potential for a workaround.