# Unable to write to characteristic via Chrome browser on Android 10

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

I am using Web Bluetooth API to write to a characteristic of a PCB board. I am able to successfully write to the characteristic via Chrome on Windows laptop.

If i try the same code via Chrome on Android 10, I get a DOM Exception: GATT Error Unknown.

I am writing a Uint8Array of length 493. I tried writing the entire data and also in chunks of 10. In both cases, I am getting an error in Mobile device.

Can someone please help?

I am using Chrome browser version 91.

UPDATE:
Added Code Snippet. I am calling a Python API to fetch data to be written to the characteristic and converting the data to Uint8Array. I tried to write the entire data via mobile but it wasn't working. Found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65446522/different-behavior-of-chrome-on-desktop-and-android-mobile-while-sending-data-to) which says to write data in chunks. So I tried that as well. Still same error.

[image]

UPDATE 2: I tried the methods `writeValue` and `writeValueWithoutResponse`. I am getting GATT server disconnected error. I tried [this](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/device-disconnect.html) link to try to fix the same. But it still persists. I have attached the screenshot for the same. [image]

UPDATE 3:
I tried with adding an event listener. I tried the same code from laptop and mobile device. It works on laptop successfully and gives off error on mobile. I have attached screenshots for both laptop and mobile.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Some questions for you:
- Does it work with only 10 bytes (not the full array) both on Windows 10 and Android?
- Do you see a difference when using `writeValue()` or `writeValueWithoutResponse()` instead of `writeValueWithResponse()`?
- Can you share logs?

Comment: It looks like you've filed a Chromium bug at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1205299 as well.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaufort yes I have filed a chromium bug as well. I tried with only 10 bytes too. It does not work. I have so far tried with only writeValueWithResponse(). I will try with the other two methods you have specified and update the results.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaufort I have added the update.

Comment: You may want to print a log with `bluetoothDevice.addEventListener('gattserverdisconnected', function() {  console.log('Disconnected'); } );`. I suspect your bluetooth device may disconnect when sending wrong bytes (unexpected size/content).
It may be good to know when exactly and what triggers this behaviour.

Were you able to grab logs? See https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/file-web-bluetooth-bugs

Comment: @FrançoisBeaufort I have added an update. I did add the event listener and tried to reconnect the device and perform functionalities after the reconnection. But that also did not work. I was unable to get the logs though from the mobile device as that was not coming up for me.  Anything else I can try that can solve this issue?

Comment: Thank you! It would really help to get adb logs from the Android device. Where do you block? I may be able to help  you get those.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaufort I will try to add the logs or error today. I also wanted to inquire if this can be tried on raspberry pi. If we can get it to work raspberry  pi, then that would also work for us.

Comment: Let me know when you get logs.

Answer (score 0):

To get help you likely need to reduce the problem to simple code
samples that you can share.  Ideally these work with common devices that others can test too.

https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/file-web-bluetooth-bugs includes tips on how to capture logs and test with other devices.